# can't get my web site, on IIS, to work with URL beginning with www

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows, azure, iis

I added my vb.net web app to IIS 8 on my Azure Windows 2012 server R2 VM.
Then, I did IIS > right-click Sites > Add Web Site
and set "Site name" to my_site.org
and set Physical path to project directory for my web site
and set "Host name" also to my_site.org.

Works great.  From Internet, I browse to http://my_site.org and it runs OK.

Now I want people to also browse to www.my_site.org 
but when I Add Web Site, just like above, but for www.my_site.org
it adds ok, but when I select www.my_site.org and click IIS Browse www.my_site.org browser pops up but reads "webpage cannot be found" 
Nor can I browse it from Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Because what is WWW? essentially that is a subdomain that you would need WWW to exist for it to load WWW.

Best option may be to set up domain forwarding to WWW, maybe a CNAME in your domain options?

Answer (score 0):

From Azure documentation, "You must also provide the domain or subdomain alias for the CNAME, such as www if you want to create an alias for www.customdomain.com. If you want to create an alias for the root domain, it may be listed as the '@' symbol in your registrar's DNS tools."

More at: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

Hope this helps! :)

- Shahed